# Angular x-editable show some form control onchange

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have an angular x-editable [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/NfPcH/15193/) where i am trying to show / hide a form control based on the status value like,

```
  <div ng-show="user.status == '1'">
      <span class="title">Show: </span>
      <span editable-text="user.showfield" e-name="showfield">{{ user.showfield || 'empty' }}</span>
    </div>
```

It will be shown only when i save the form. How can I make it show when changing the control field itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed demo** <kbd>**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/smallyin/qw5y66nr/1/)**</kbd>.

You can get there by directive `e-ng-change`.

Sample codes:

```
    <div>
      <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
      <span class="title">Status: </span>

      <!-- by e-ng-change, get result before save, and asign to user.showstatus -->
      <span editable-select="user.status" e-ng-change="user.showstatus=$data;" e-name="status" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
        {{ (statuses | filter:{value: user.status})[0].text || 'Not set' }}
      </span>
    </div>  

     <!-- toggle display by user.showstatus -->
     <div ng-show="user.showstatus == '1'">
      <span class="title">Show: </span>
      <span editable-text="user.showfield" e-name="showfield">{{ user.showfield || 'empty' }}</span>
    </div>
```

**Credit:** [Angular x-editable github issue #105](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/105)

Comment: What about upon cancel? i mean hiding if cancel clicked?

Comment: figured out. can be achieved by `oncancel` event